# Testing named_scope with Mongoid and rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm newbie in RoR, and I am trying to test a simple named_scope for my Model.

But I don't know if I have a problem in my model (I'm using mongoid), in my code test (I'm using rspec) or in my factory. I got this error

> Mongoid::Errors::InvalidCollection:
>          Access to the collection for Movement is not allowed since it is an embedded document, please access a collection from the root
>   document.

My models

```
class Movement
    include Mongoid::Document
    field :description, :type => String
    embedded_in :category

    named_scope :top, lambda { |number| { :limit => (number.size > 0 ? number : 10) } }    
end

class Category
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name
  embeds_many :movement
end
```

My factory, con factory_girl

```
Factory.define :movement do |m|
  m.amount 24
  m.date "30/10/2011"
  m.description "Beer"
  m.association :category, :factory => :category
end

Factory.define :category do |c|
  c.name "Drink"
end
```

My test

```
describe "when i have a movement list" do
  it "recent method should return last 2 movements" do
    @movements = (1..3).collect { Factory(:movement) }
    recent_movements = Movement.top(2)
    recent_movements.should have(2).entries
  end
end
```

And the error:

> Mongoid::Errors::InvalidCollection:
>         Access to the collection for Movement is not allowed since it is an embedded >document, 
>   please access a collection from the root document.

I tried a little change in my factory.

```
   Factory.define :movement do |m|
      m.amount 24
      m.date "30/10/2011"
      m.description "Beer" 
      m.category { [ Factory.build(:category) ] }
    end
```

But then I got other different error:

> Failure/Error: @movements = (1..3).collect { Factory(:movement) }
>       NoMethodError:
>         undefined method `reflect_on_association' for #

Could someone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just had a the same error in my app. I ended up having an error in my class and that solved my problem.